# I'm trying to add a small javascript piece to a web page, but it just displays the code on the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Like the title says, I'm trying to add a small javascript piece to a web page, but it keeps glitching and it just shows the code, can I get some help?

(For those who want to know, here's the javascript piece):

```
var draw = function() {
background(0,0,0);
strokeWeight(10);
stroke(0,255,0);
ellipse(mouseX,mouseY,350,350);
   strokeWeight(5);
   fill(0,0,0);
   stroke(0,255,0);
   ellipse(mouseX,mouseY,300,300);
   strokeWeight(1);
stroke(0,255, 0);
fill(0,0,0);
ellipse(mouseX,mouseY,250,250);
ellipse(mouseX,mouseY,155,155);
ellipse(mouseX,mouseY,145,145);
ellipse(mouseX,mouseY,135,135);
ellipse(mouseX,mouseY,125,125);
ellipse(mouseX,mouseY,115,115);
ellipse(mouseX,mouseY,105,105);
ellipse(mouseX,mouseY,95,95);
ellipse(mouseX,mouseY,85,85);
ellipse(mouseX,mouseY,75,75);
ellipse(mouseX,mouseY,65,65);
ellipse(mouseX,mouseY,55,55);
ellipse(mouseX,mouseY,45,45);
ellipse(mouseX,mouseY,35,35);
ellipse(mouseX,mouseY,25,25);
ellipse(mouseX,mouseY,15,15);
ellipse(mouseX,mouseY,5,5);
line(200,0,mouseX,mouseY-150);
line(0,200,mouseX-150,mouseY);
line(400,200,mouseX+150,mouseY);
line(200,400,mouseX,mouseY+150);
fill(0,0,0);
line(0,0,mouseX,mouseY);
line(400,0,mouseX,mouseY);
line(0,400,mouseX,mouseY);
line(400,400,mouseX,mouseY);
fill(0,0,0);
stroke(0,255,0);    
    line(250,250,250,150);
    line(250,150,150,150);
    line(150,150,150,250);
    line(150,250,250,250);
ellipse(250,250,10,10);
ellipse(250,150,10,10);
ellipse(150,150,10,10);
ellipse(150,250,10,10);

};
```

Comment: Is it wrapped with a <script></script> tag?

Comment: you need to put it between <script> </script> tags

Comment: Not only do you need to wrap the code in a script tag, but you need to call the function as well. So after your `var draw = function(){ ... };` code, you need to write `draw();` to invoke that function.

I'd suggest reading up on some basics of JavaScript if you need help with that. [You Don't Know JS](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS) is a good free ebook that is often recommended.

Comment: Thanks for the book link, I'll check it out! But umm, where do I put the  `draw();` at?

Answer (score 1):

Anytime you have javascript on your page you must wrap it with `<script></script>` tags. Try adding this to your page instead.

```
<script>

var draw = function() {
    background(0,0,0);
    strokeWeight(10);
    stroke(0,255,0);
    ellipse(mouseX,mouseY,350,350);
    strokeWeight(5);
    fill(0,0,0);
    stroke(0,255,0);
    ellipse(mouseX,mouseY,300,300);
    strokeWeight(1);
    stroke(0,255, 0);
    fill(0,0,0);
    ellipse(mouseX,mouseY,250,250);
    ellipse(mouseX,mouseY,155,155);
    ellipse(mouseX,mouseY,145,145);
    ellipse(mouseX,mouseY,135,135);
    ellipse(mouseX,mouseY,125,125);
    ellipse(mouseX,mouseY,115,115);
    ellipse(mouseX,mouseY,105,105);
    ellipse(mouseX,mouseY,95,95);
    ellipse(mouseX,mouseY,85,85);
    ellipse(mouseX,mouseY,75,75);
    ellipse(mouseX,mouseY,65,65);
    ellipse(mouseX,mouseY,55,55);
    ellipse(mouseX,mouseY,45,45);
    ellipse(mouseX,mouseY,35,35);
    ellipse(mouseX,mouseY,25,25);
    ellipse(mouseX,mouseY,15,15);
    ellipse(mouseX,mouseY,5,5);
    line(200,0,mouseX,mouseY-150);
    line(0,200,mouseX-150,mouseY);
    line(400,200,mouseX+150,mouseY);
    line(200,400,mouseX,mouseY+150);
    fill(0,0,0);
    line(0,0,mouseX,mouseY);
    line(400,0,mouseX,mouseY);
    line(0,400,mouseX,mouseY);
    line(400,400,mouseX,mouseY);
    fill(0,0,0);
    stroke(0,255,0);    
    line(250,250,250,150);
    line(250,150,150,150);
    line(150,150,150,250);
    line(150,250,250,250);
    ellipse(250,250,10,10);
    ellipse(250,150,10,10);
    ellipse(150,150,10,10);
    ellipse(150,250,10,10);
};

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, you need to wrap any in-line Javascript inside a script tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var draw = function() {
 background(0,0,0);
 strokeWeight(10);
 stroke(0,255,0);
 ellipse(mouseX,mouseY,350,350);
    strokeWeight(5);
    fill(0,0,0);
    stroke(0,255,0);
    ellipse(mouseX,mouseY,300,300);
    strokeWeight(1);
 stroke(0,255, 0);
 fill(0,0,0);
  ...
 };
</script>
```